# R programming - not deleting the right column

Tags: r, variables, linear-regression

I am writing to paste here my code.
I am following an online course in R and I was trying to automate a multiple variables regression. I have tried to check what's going on and at the beginning, it works, but when it comes to the last two variables, it enters in a loop and does not eliminate them, even though it enters in the if.
At the end, I have this error

```
Error in if (maxVar > sl) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is the code

```
backwardElimination <-function(training,sl) {
  numVar=length(training)
  funzRegressor = lm(formula = profit ~.,
               data = training)
  p = summary(funzRegressor)$coefficients[,4]
  maxVar = max(p)
  if (maxVar > sl){
    for (j in c(1:numVar)){
      if (maxVar == p[j]) {
        training = training[, -j]
        backwardElimination(training,sl)
      }
    }
  }
  return(summary(funzRegressor))
}
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: this is the rest of my code

```
#importing dataset
dataset = read.csv('50_Startups.csv')


# Encoding categorical data
dataset$State = factor(dataset$State,
                         levels = c('New York', 'California', 'Florida'),
                         labels = c(1, 2, 3))

#splitting in train / test set 
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(dataset$Profit, SplitRatio = 4/5)
trainingSet = subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
testSet = subset(dataset, split == FALSE)
#Transforming state in dummy variables
trainingSet$State = factor(trainingSet$State)
dummies = model.matrix(~trainingSet$State)
trainingSet = cbind(trainingSet,dummies)
profit = trainingSet$Profit
trainingSet = trainingSet[, -4]
trainingSet = trainingSet[, -4]
trainingSet = cbind(trainingSet,profit)
#calling the function
SL = 0.05
backwardElimination(trainingSet, SL)
```

Comment: it gives me this error `Error in funzRegressor$coefficients[, 4] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: 6
I need to take the columns of the p-values

Exactly

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you have an `NA` instead of a boolean value in your `if` statement.

```
if (NA) {}
## Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Either your `p` contains `NA`, either `sl` is `NA`.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post with the rest of my code.

Comment: Try putting `Profit` with a capital P in your `lm` formula

Comment: No, it is not that, because when I created the dummy variables, I renamed it with `profit`, it would not work with  `Profit`.
I made a bit of debugging and it is going inside the if, but not eliminating the column I want...
Maybe there is a logical mistake that I cannot spot in `training = training[, -j]`

Comment: can you provide `summary(funzRegressor)`

Comment: `Call:
lm(formula = profit ~ ., data = training)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-33128  -4865      5   6098  18065 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           4.965e+04  7.637e+03   6.501 1.94e-07 ***
R.D.Spend             7.986e-01  5.604e-02  14.251 6.70e-16 ***
Administration       -2.942e-02  5.828e-02  -0.505    0.617    
Marketing.Spend       3.268e-02  2.127e-02   1.537    0.134  
trainingSet$State2  1.213e+02  3.751e+03   0.032    0.974
trainingSet$State3  2.376e+02  4.127e+03   0.058    0.954`

Answer (score 0):

Your intercepts are also fed back in the next step of modeling, you need to get rid of it before moving to the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried removing intercepts and no mistakes...
But probably there is another logical mistake.
The NA is from the intercepts for sure, but if I remove them the function goes straight to the return, without going into the if.
So it returns the summary of the complete regression, without removing the not relevant variables.

Comment: Can you browse trainingSet and see if there is an unexpected 'intercept' variable?

Comment: I can see that `trainingSet = cbind(trainingSet,dummies)` is causing problem as `dummies' has an `intercept` variable. Remove that using `trainingSet = cbind(trainingSet,dummies[,-1])` and you should be through.

Comment: Also, there is a need to control the flow while recursively calling the function.

Comment: That's what I did, but after removing the intercept variable it goes straight to `return(summary(funzRegressor))` without removing the columns that are not significant for the regression model. Don't know why

Comment: It is because of recursive calls to the function and improper control flow in the code, you need to break when all insignificant variables are removed.as of now 'return' is executed more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate your error with R in-built dataset `state.x77`

```
dataset <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
dataset$State <- rownames(dataset) 
dataset$profit <- rnorm(nrow(dataset))

backwardElimination <-function(training,sl) {
    if (!"profit" %in% names(training)) return(NULL)

    numVar=length(training)
    funzRegressor = lm(formula = profit ~.,
        data = training)
    p = summary(funzRegressor)$coefficients[,4]
    maxVar = max(p)
    #print(funzRegressor)

    if (maxVar > sl){
        for (j in c(1:numVar)){
            if (maxVar == p[j]) {
                training = training[, -j]
                backwardElimination(training,sl)
            }
        }
    }
    return(summary(funzRegressor))
}
backwardElimination(dataset, 0.05)
```

There are NAs in some of your betas and all the p-values becomes NaN. Do you need to regress within states? Otherwise you can remove the State column to remove the error.

There will be another error when you reach the boundary case in your recursion, which you can fix :)

Comment: I would like to regress the state too, anyway I have tried removing them, just to check, and now it gives me this error 
`Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In summary.lm(funzRegressor) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
2: In summary.lm(funzRegressor) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
3: In summary.lm(funzRegressor) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
4: In summary.lm(funzRegressor) :`

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the data. most likely one of the column = profit column